Process the result set inside BatchReader before passing it to BatchProcessor
I am using JpaPagingItemReader to read from DB. It returns List<Object[]>.
I need to process these records and create another objects which I need to send further to the BatchProcessor.
That's how my batch configuration looks like:

    @Bean
        public Step loadDataFromDBStep() {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("loadDataFromDBStep")
                    .<MyEntity, MyEntity> chunk(chunkSize)
                    .reader(getBatchReader())
                    .processor(processor)
                    .writer(batchWriter)
                    .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                    .build();
        }
    
    
        @Bean
        public JpaPagingItemReader<MyEntity> getBatchReader() {
            JpaPagingItemReader<MyEntity> reader = new BatchReader();
    
            reader.setName("getDataFromReader");
            reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager);
            reader.setQueryProvider(queryProvider());
            reader.setPageSize(pageSize);      // set to 1000
    
            return reader;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public QueryProvider queryProvider () {
            return new QueryProvider();
        }


Currently the BatchReader has just the overridden method defined:

public class BatchReader extends JpaPagingItemReader{   
@Override
protected void doReadPage() {
    Long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.doReadPage();
    Long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Long timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
    LOGGER.info("Data retrieved: page={}, timeTaken={}ms", 
getPage(), timeTaken);
}

}


I need to process the List<Object[]> to create another objects and also persist these objects into DB before the control goes to the Processor.

Why don't you create a first step in your job that reads your List<Object[]>, then in the processor you create your new object that you then give to a writer that will persist it in DB for you. Then in a second step, you read the data you wrote in step 1, and process it any way you want to.
